# diff staged and unstaged files in diff

Tags: git, version-control, diff

Let's say I have file

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

and I changed it like this

```
1
222
3
444
5
```

now I applied patch with **git add -p** and added only the first change (2 -> 222)

What I can do to view unstaged changes againts staged to see output like this:

```
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
- 4
+ 444
```

Comment: does `git diff` solve your purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run `git diff, which compares your index against your stage, not your head. Your already added changes (222) will not be displayed because they are already in your stage, so you will see the changed 444 line only.